# Creating a method that returns an array of all items in a set (linked list)

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been trying to find the solution to the errors I'm getting for this method:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
        int size = 1;
        Node curr = head;

        while (curr.getNext() != null) {
            size++;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }

        Object[] arr = new Object[size];
        arr[0] = head.getItem();

        curr = head;

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = curr.getNext().getItem();
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

The goal of the method is to simply return an object array of all the items in the set. This method is part of my class, "Set", which is a child class of my "LinkedList" class, which gives me access to the instance variable head. The method will take my list and add the first element, and second element to the array, and then instead of continuing on to the third, fourth, etc. it simply populates the rest of the array with the second element in my list.

Could anyone give me some advice? Thank you!

Comment: Which line gives you a NullPointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
        int size = 1;
        Node curr = head;

        while (curr.getNext() != null) {
            size++;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }

        Object[] arr = new Object[size];
        //arr[0] = head; // Shouldn't be arr[0] = head.getItem(); ???
        arr[0] = head.getItem();

        Node curr = head; // You should set curr to head;

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = curr.getNext().getItem();
            curr = curr.getNext(); // Otherwise you can't go to next element;
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: This cleared up a lot of my errors, but now after attempting to use the method. It adds the first element, then the second element, and fills the rest of the array with that second element instead of going to the third, fourth, etc. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @Nick yes you should set curr to curr.getNext() see new update

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for your help, I understand why I was having my issues. Still learning how to logically think through problems such as this and see the errors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to reset `curr` back to the `head` before you start your second iteration. Otherwise, you are starting at the end instead of the beginning.